# Running eventlet server in bottle framework

Tags: python, bottle, eventlet

i see something like this in bottle.py version 0.9. Does that means. i can run bottle server as a eventlet server.

```
class EventletServer(ServerAdapter):
""" Untested """
def run(self, handler):
    from eventlet import wsgi, listen
    wsgi.server(listen((self.host, self.port)), handler
```

)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atlast figured out. how to run bottle server as eventlet in bottle framework.Just should pass the argument server='' inside run. list of supported servers [Server adapters in bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#deployment)

```
run(server='eventlet',host='localhost', port=8080, reloader=True)
```